# Using the COPY command in a Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to get log files from 2 diff directories and copy them into same target directory based on some conditions on logfilenames. Logic of getting logs based on logfilenames is working fine and they are printed to console.

Below is the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
dir /b "C:\temp1\*web_feed*.out*.gz"^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.) do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130931" echo %%F
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "C:\temp2\*web_feed*.out*.gz"^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.) do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130931" echo %%F
pause "Please enter any key to continue"
```

Now the above script brings log files from `c:\temp1` and `c:\temp2` based on date conditions and print to console using `echo`, but I want those log files to be copied to target directory. Where do I need to add the copy condition so that the logfiles obtained from `c:\temp1` and `c:\temp2` directory are copied into `c:\temp3` directory?

Also can I accomplish the duplicate steps of coping log files from 2 different directories in single step, instead of 2 separate steps for separate directories.

I am novice to batch scripting, my script is not working when I add `copy` command.

Comment: Does the script above even working?I can see some syntax issues.What is the format of `*web_feed*.out*.gz` files?

Comment: Format of file:20130401.001_visual_sciences_web_feed.out

Comment: Above script is working fine, actually i have added 2 scripts in above , one for c:\temp1 and other from c:\temp2, For one                                        @ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b "c:\temp1\*feed.out.gz"^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.'
) do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130930" echo %%F

Comment: Now i want the filtered log filnames to be copied into some other directory say c:\temp3, for that i am using copy cmmand at end  as, but it is not working                                                       @ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b "c:\temp1\*feed.out.gz"^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.'
) do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130930" xcopy "%%F" "c:\temp3\" please suggest

Comment: Format YYYYMMDD.xxx_*feed.out.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script was broken, I have corrected the obvious errors I think and added code to copy the files to `c:\temp3` and also added a prefix to the filenames - as if the filenames in the two folders are the same then they will overwrite each other.

```
@echo off
md "c:\temp3" 2>nul
pushd "C:\temp1\"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "*web_feed*.out*.gz"^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\."') do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130931" copy "%%F" "c:\temp3\temp1-%%F"
popd
pushd "C:\temp2\"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "*web_feed*.out*.gz"^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\."') do if "%%F" geq "20130101" if "%%F" lss "20130931" copy "%%F" "c:\temp3\temp2-%%F"
popd
pause
```

Comment: Thanks ,its working now , also i am not getting how to use for loop to iterate through the 2 directories(temp1 and temp2) , as they were doing the same thing , So that I want to avoid 2 individual steps ,Can you please let me know how we can do that ?

Comment: They are returning different files.  You need to separate them and two loops is easy.  Without further details on filenames and differences between the two sets of files, we're guessing.